# How to format "2021-01-19T12:50:00Z" to: 2021-01-19 12:50:00

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular and rxjs.

So I have this:

```
  x: console.log(res.map(date => date.dt))
```

And it returns this:

```
0: "2021-01-19T12:50:00Z"
1: "2021-01-19T12:51:00Z"
2: "2021-01-19T12:52:00Z"
3: "2021-01-19T12:53:00Z"
4: "2021-01-19T12:54:00Z"
5: "2021-01-19T12:55:00Z"
6: "2021-01-19T12:56:00Z"
7: "2021-01-19T12:57:00Z"
8: "2021-01-19T12:59:00Z"
```

But of course that is not readable.

SO I want to convert it to for example this:  '2021-01-19 12:50:00',

So: yyyy-MM-dd HH-MM-SS

But so what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe do something like this:

```js
    // this is taking a date string, if you are passing the date obj directly then no need to pass it to `new Date()`
    function cleanTheDate(dateStr) {
        return new Date(dateStr).toISOString().
            replace(/T/, ' ').
            replace(/\..+/, '')
    }
```

Comment: ah, oke, so still a regular expression. Oke, thanks.

Comment: I mean you could do it without regex but I find this to be cleaner than non-regex ones. Or you could use some 3rd party modules, but not necessary for such simpler tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to write your own date formatter function. Something like:

```js
const formatDate = (inputDate) => {
  return `${inputDate.getFullYear()}-${addLeadingZero(inputDate.getMonth() + 1)}-${addLeadingZero(inputDate.getDate())} ${addLeadingZero(inputDate.getHours())}:${addLeadingZero(inputDate.getMinutes())}:${addLeadingZero(inputDate.getSeconds())}`;
}

const addLeadingZero = (input) => {
  return input < 10 ? `0${input}` : input;
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

ANGULAR HAS ITS OWN DATE PIPE FOR HTML AND formatDate() FUNCTION FOR TS FILE

Hi, as I mentioned above, you can use Angular's in-built pipes

Date Pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

formatDate() function: https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

```
// If you want to format the date in the HTML template

// Syntax
{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}


// Example
<p>
  <strong>
     Birthday in format dd/MM/yyyy :
  </strong>
  {{ birthday | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
</p>
-------------------------------------------------------------

// If you want to format the date in the component.ts file

// Syntax
formatDate(value: string | number | Date, format: string, locale: string, timezone?: string): string

// Example
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

const format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
const myDate = '2021-01-20';
const locale = 'en-US';
const formattedDate = formatDate(myDate, format, locale);
```